# Rotate Node To Root Of BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

So I have my functions to rotate my nodes in a BST:

```
void BST::rotate_with_left_child(BNode *&t){

    BNode *t1 = t->left;
    t->left = t1->right;
    t1->right = t;
    t->node_height = max(height(t->left),height(t->right))+1;
    t1->node_height = max(height(t1->left),t->node_height)+1;
    t = t1;

}

void BST::double_rotate_with_left_child(BNode *&t){

    rotate_with_right_child(t->left);
    rotate_with_left_child(t);

}

void BST::rotate_with_right_child(BNode *&t){

    BNode *t1 = t->right;
    t->right = t1->left;
    t1->left = t;
    t->node_height = max(height(t->right),height(t->left))+1;
    t1->node_height = max(height(t1->right),t->node_height)+1;
    t = t1;

}

void BST::double_rotate_with_right_child(BNode *&t){

    rotate_with_left_child(t->right);
    rotate_with_right_child(t);

}
```

and say I found a node that I want to rotate to the root of the tree. How would I go about writing a function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Following code is not tested at all. It's just too illustrate the ideas. Code is all the way at the bottom.

Assumptions:

- Nodes have no parent link, and a non-root node cannot tell whether it is the left child or right child of its parent. Otherwise, the algorithm can be slightly simplified.
- A node has a left link and a right link, which is evident from your code.
- **This algorithm *does not* take into account of whether the final tree is balanced.** If you require it to be balanced, then you can stop reading this answer and you might want to look at Splay Trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree

I will assume that you obtain a node by some kind of search routine. Now, the idea is, simply maintain:

1. a stack of the nodes you have seen on the search
2. direction of the links traversed in the search

For example, given this tree:

```
             15
            /  \
           2   35
              /  \
             28   42
            /  \
          19    31
```

and we searched for the key `19`, which is inside the tree. Now, we want to rotate 19 all the way to the top.

`NodeStack`, a stack of nodes from bottom of stack to top: `[15, 35, 28, 19]` <-- top of stack

`DirStack`, a stack of link directions traversed: `[RIGHT, LEFT, LEFT]` <-- top of stack

We are assuming as search hit here. So the first thing we should do is to retrieve the topmost element of `NodeStack`, which is the node we want to rotate to the top. In this case, it is the node with key `19`. After this step, both stacks look like:

`NodeStack`: `[15, 35, 28]` <-- top of stack

`DirStack`: `[RIGHT, LEFT, LEFT]` <-- top of stack

Next, the main loop runs until `DirStack` is empty. We pop one element from both stacks. The element popped from `NodeStack` is the parent of the node we wish to rotate to the top, and the element popped from `DirStack` indicates the direction of the link from the node we just popped to the future root node.

At the first iteration of the loop, we have the node `28` and link direction `LEFT`, so node `19` is the left child of node `28`.

It should not be hard to see that we should rotate opposite to the direction that we just popped, so we should rotate the parent node left if the direction is `RIGHT`, and rotate the parent node right if the direction is `LEFT`. Since the direction here is `LEFT`, we rotate the parent node `28` **right**. This can be achieved by calling the `rotate_with_left_child` function on node `28`.

The tree becomes

```
             15
            /  \
           2   35
              /  \
             19   42
              \
               28
                \
                 31
```

notice that `28` becomes a right child, hence this is a **right rotation**. I'm pretty sure this is the correct terminology. As wikipedia is down right now, I cannot verify this, but this question shows that I'm using the correct terminology:

[Code with explanation for binary tree rotation (left OR right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597650/code-with-explanation-for-binary-tree-rotation-left-or-right)

State of the stacks now:

`NodeStack`: `[15, 35]` <-- top of stack

`DirStack`: `[RIGHT, LEFT]` <-- top of stack

The stacks are not empty, so we pop `35` and `LEFT` from the two stacks. We perform a right rotation using the **rotate_with_left_child** function on the node `35`, to get this tree:

```
             15
            /  \
           2    19
                 \
                 35
                /  \
               28  42
                \
                 31
```

Our node is now closer to becoming root. Stacks now:

`NodeStack`: `[15]`

`DirStack`: `[RIGHT]`

We pop node `15` and direction `RIGHT`. Now, we perform a **left rotation** using the `rotate_with_right_child` function on node `15`, and we obtain this final tree:

```
             19
            /  \
           15   35
          /     / \
         2     28 42
                \
                 31
```

Tadah! We are now done. Here's the code, using `std::stack` from STL.

```
// NOTE: None of the code here is tested, so some errors are expected.

// Used to indicate direction of links traversed during the search
enum Direction {
  LEFT, RIGHT
};

// This function rotates the node at the top of nodeStack to the root of the tree.
// It assumes that the nodeStack is non-empty, and that nodeStack has one more
// element than dirStack
//
// nodeStack - stack of nodes encountered during search
// dirStack  - direction of links traversed during search
void rotate_to_top(stack<BSTNode *>& nodeStack, stack<Direction>& dirStack) {
    // remove the future root node. actually this assignment is not needed
    // NOTE: You might also want to check if the nodeStack is empty before doing this
    BSTNode* root = nodeStack.top();
    nodeStack.pop();

    // main loop. this is done until the dirStack is empty
    while (!dirStack.empty()) {
        Direction d = dirStack.top();
        dirStack.pop();
        BSTNode *par = nodeStack.top();
        nodeStack.top();
        // perform the proper rotation
        if (d == LEFT) {
            rotate_with_left_child(par);
        } else {
            rotate_with_right_child(par);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Hey, can we chat is a private room?

Comment: ok sure, but how do i do that? i'm not too familiar with this feature of stackoverflow